# How to loop and count how many times each game has been played?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

```
game_record = [['*', 'G02', 'G05', 'G07', 'G08', 'G10'], 
          ['P001', '1', '0', '-1', '503', '1'], 
          ['P067', '1', '1', '0', '-1', '503'], 
          ['P218', '0', '1', '1', '-1', '-1'], 
          ['P101', '0', '0', '1', '1', '503'], 
          ['P456', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1']]
```

Info for game_record list data:

- * = nothing, just a sign
- GXX = game_id
- PXXX = player_id
- 1 = playing game and win (game finished and recorded)
- 0 = playing game and lose (game finished and recorded)
- -1 = not playing the game (not recorded)
- 503 = in an on-going game (game not finished and not recorded)

for example:

- G02 has been played and finished by 5 players with total of 3 players win and 2 players lose.
- G08 has been played and finished by 2 players with total of 2 players win.

therefore only '1' and '0' matter for the record.

I want to loop this 2D-list to count how many times each game (game_id) has been played, win, and lose by a player. Then store them to dictionary.

Expected Output:

```
Game_info = {G02: [5, 3, 2], G05: [5, 3, 2], G07: [3, 2, 1], G08: [2, 2, 0], G10: [1, 1, 0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with a dictionary with all the games in `game_record` initialized with `[0,0,0]`

```
Game_info = { game:[0,0,0] for game in game_record[0] if game != "*"}
```

then you can just iterate through `game_record` and update values in `Game_info`

```
n, m = len(game_record[0]), len(game_record)

for y in range(1,n):
     g_id = game_record[0][y]
     for x in range(1,m):
         res = game_record[x][y]
         if res == '1':
             Game_info[g_id][0] += 1
             Game_info[g_id][1] += 1
         elif res == '0':
             Game_info[g_id][0] += 1
             Game_info[g_id][2] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save a loop by using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) and Boolean arrays:

```py
import numpy as np

results = np.array(game_record)[1:, 1:].astype(int)

won_by_game = (results == 1).sum(axis=0)
lost_by_game = (results == 0).sum(axis=0)
played_by_game = won_by_game + lost_by_game

game_info = {game: [played, won, lost] 
             for game, played, won, lost in 
             zip(game_record[0][1:], played_by_game, 
                 won_by_game, lost_by_game)}
game_info
```

```
{'G02': [5, 3, 2],
 'G05': [5, 3, 2],
 'G07': [3, 2, 1],
 'G08': [2, 2, 0],
 'G10': [1, 1, 0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
game_record = [
    ['*', 'G02', 'G05', 'G07', 'G08', 'G10'], 
    ['P001', '1', '0', '-1', '503', '1'], 
    ['P067', '1', '1', '0', '-1', '503'], 
    ['P218', '0', '1', '1', '-1', '-1'], 
    ['P101', '0', '0', '1', '1', '503'], 
    ['P456', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1']
]


res = {}

for i in range(1, 6):
    w, l = 0, 0
    label = game_record[0][i]
    for j in range(1, 6):   
        v = game_record[j][i]  # access matrix value (column-wise) except row 0 and col 0
        if v == '-1' or v == '503':
            continue
        if v == '1':
            w += 1
        else:
            l += 1
    g = w + l
    res.update({label: [g, w, l]})

print(res)
# {'G02': [5, 3, 2], 'G05': [5, 3, 2], 'G07': [3, 2, 1], 'G08': [2, 2, 0], 'G10': [1, 1, 0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution without library.

```
names = game_record[0][1:]  
game_record = [*zip(*game_record[1:])][1:]  # Transpose and drop
game_record = [list(map(int, x)) for x in game_record]  # Turn into int
solution = dict()
for i, game in enumerate(game_record):
    game = [x for x in game if x not in [-1, 503]] # Filter unwanted
    solution[names[i]] = [len(game), sum(game), len(game) - sum(game)]
```